# SQL Er диаграмма помогите объеденить таблицы

Tags: mysql

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в таблицу заказы можно было выбрать вид доставки(либо точка выдачи, лиюо адрес доставки) никак сообразить не могу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А кто мешает для пункта выдачи писать в поле адреса собсно адрес пункта выдачи?

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить поле 'тип доставки' в таблицу Заказы. В этом поле писать, какая доставка на адрес или на точку. Два поля тип доставки и id доставки однозначно будут определять и нужную таблицу и запись в ней.